# Android: Prevent TextView scroll programmatically over border

Tags: android, scroll

I scroll a TextView programmatically in onDispatchKeyEvent. When I scroll a lot I can move the Text over or under the border so that it is only shown half.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MOVE_HOME && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

outputTextView.scrollBy(0, +50);

}
}
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remember your current position and check if you can sroll any more

```
curr_pos += 50
if(curr_pos < outputTextView.getBottom()){
    outputTextView.scrollBy(0, +50);
}else{
    curr_pos -=50
}
```

Or try to override [.onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) which is called by [.scrollBy(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollBy(int,%20int)).